# Use of Guard Malloc(Mac OS) for debugging in Qt Creator

Tags: c++, macos, debugging, qt

In Xcode, there is the possibility to use the so called [guard malloc](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/darwin/reference/manpages/man3/libgmalloc.3.html) flag, to simplify debugging malloc and pointers stuff.

I wonder how can I use that flag on Qt Creator, when debugging.

In man pages they give the example of using it with gdb:

```
% cc -g -o gmalloctest gmalloctest.c
% gdb gmalloctest
Reading symbols for shared libraries .. done
(gdb) set env DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES /usr/lib/libgmalloc.dylib
(gdb) r
```

How do I tell Qt Creator to "set env" when debugging?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set environment variables in Creator's project Run Settings panel: http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qtcreator-2.4/creator-run-settings.html

Expand "Run Environment" to add/edit variables. They are set when you run/debug your project.

Comment: It works. Very good. However guard malloc is to heavy for a simple Qt app (or the other way around). xD